# Possible output sequence of A B C D using only single stack?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack, queue

I want to determine the possible outputs of the sequence A B C D using only a single stack.

I'm trying to produce the output A D B C, but didn't succeed.

What are the possible output sequences?

Comment: In A B C D, if D is at the top of the stack, then popping order will be D C B A as stack is last in first out.

Comment: it is not D C A B?

Comment: No, stack follows last in first out principle.

Answer (score 1):

Given an input sequence A B C D, and an empty stack, you have the following actions at your disposal:

1. Get the next value from the input sequence and push it on the stack
2. Pop a value from the stack and output it
3. Get the next value from the input sequence and output it

Action 3 is really the same as performing action 1 followed by action 2, so we can ignore action 3 as a possible action.

In order to output all input values, we thus need to execute four times action 1, and four times action 2. We can play with the order, taking into account that action 2 can only be executed if there is still a value on the stack.

So these are the possible series of actions you can perform:

```
series of actions | output
------------------+-------------
         12121212 | ABCD
         12121122 | ABDC
         12112212 | ACBD
         12112122 | ACDB
         12111222 | ADCB
         11221212 | BACD
         11221122 | BADC
         11212212 | BCAD
         11212122 | BCDA
         11211222 | BDCA
         11122212 | CBAD
         11122122 | CBDA
         11121222 | CDBA
         11112222 | DCBA
```

This list can be produced with a little recursive function. For example, via this JavaScript implementation:

```js
function recur(input, stack, output, actions) {
    if (output.length === 4) {
        console.log(actions, output);
        return;
    }
    if (stack.length > 0) {
        recur(input, stack.slice(0, stack.length - 1), output + stack[stack.length - 1], actions + "2");
    }
    if (input.length > 0) {
        recur(input.slice(1), stack + input[0], output, actions + "1");
    }
}
recur("ABCD", "", "", "");
```

As you can see, it is impossible to produce the output ADBC.

We could try with the following actions:

- put A on the stack
- pull A from the stack and output. Output is A
- put B on the stack
- put C on the stack
- put D on the stack
- pull D from the stack and output. Output is now AD

And now we are stuck. The stack has B at the bottom and C at the top. We can only output C now...

Comment: i think it is possible using stack (last in first out) to produce from (A,B,C,D) --> (A, D, B, C), with simple steps, please check my answer above.

Comment: I checked your answer, but you are not treating the input as a sequence and not restricting yourself to only a stack.

Comment: yes indeed, I read your comment, thank you very much for the clarification, I will add the assumption to my answer.

Comment: hello again :) ,  please sir, can you check my answer again for **Case 2: Only sequential access is allowed (no random access):**, i think i find a way to solve the problem. I illustrate the solution, then pseudo code, and at the end the source code by python. And yes i used an extra memory to hold the count of elements n.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

A B C D --> A D B C   using stack (last in, first out) is possible (case 1 and 2), not possible case 3 (for short @trincot answer is the perfect for case 3).

***Case 1:*** We assume that we have **[random access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory)** to the elements of the sequence (Based on the important clarification of ([@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot)):

- 1. go to the middle of your string ==>  A B | C D
- 2. use index id_to_left from middle to left ,  and id_to_right from middle to right
- 3. insert one element in stack using id_to_right, then one element using id_to_left
- 4. repeat action 3 until the end.
- 5. output the elements from the stack.

Demonstration :

it 1: add (C) , add (B) ==> C,B
it 2: add (D) , add (A) ==> C,B,D,A

output :  A , D, B , C

Source code using python:

```
my_list = ['A','B','C','D']

id_to_left = int(len(my_list)/2-1)
id_to_right = int(len(my_list)/2)

stack = []

# When number of elements is odd
if len(my_list) % 2 != 0:
    stack.append(my_list[id_to_right])
    id_to_right = id_to_right +1

while (id_to_left>=0):
    stack.append(my_list[id_to_right])
    stack.append(my_list[id_to_left])
    id_to_left = id_to_left-1
    id_to_right = id_to_right +1 
    
for _ in range(len(stack)):
    print(stack.pop(), end=" ")
```

The Result will be:

```
A D B C
```

***Case 2:*** Only sequential access is allowed (no random access):

```
input : 

|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
+--+  A B C D

step 1)
it1: 
> in all    > out top 3
|D |        |  |
|C |        |  |
|B |        |  |
|A |        |A |
+--+        +--+ D C B 

it2: 
> in all    > out top 2
|B |        |  |
|C |        |  |
|D |        |D |
|A |        |A |
+--+        +--+ B C 

it3: 
> in all    >  stop 
|C |    
|B |    
|D |    
|A |    
+--+    


step 2)
 
> out all       > in all  >  out all
|  |            |A |      |  |
|  |            |D |      |  |
|  |            |B |      |  |
|  |            |C |      |  |
+--+ C B D A    +--+      +--+ A D B C 

End.

Result = A D B C
```

**The pseudo code** :

```
input :  set of "n" elements

step 1:
while True :
    > in all elements from the set to stack (pop elements from the list)
    > n = n-1
    > if n < 2 stop the loop, (break)
    > out n from the stack

step 2:
> out all from the stack
> in all to stack
> out all from stack
> print result
> end.
```

Source code using python:

```
    my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    n = len(my_list)

    stack = []

    # step 1
    while (True):
        for _ in range(len(my_list)): # in all to stack
            stack.append(my_list.pop(0))
     
        n = n - 1
        if n < 2:
            break
            
        for _ in range(n):  # out n from the stack
            my_list.append(stack.pop())

    # step 2:
    for _ in range(len(stack)):  # > out all from the stack
        my_list.append(stack.pop())

    for _ in range(len(my_list)): # > in all to stack
        stack.append(my_list.pop(0))

    # > out all from stack ==> print result
    print("\n The result is : ", end=" ")
    for _ in range(len(stack)):
        print(stack.pop(), end=" ")
```

Note: the two cases, work for number of elements even or odd, you can try

- A B C D     --> A D B C
- A B x C D   --> A D B C x
- X A B C D Y --> X Y A D B C

***Case 3:*** A) Elements comes like in streaming (Only sequential access is allowed), and B) there is no space memory available, only the stack. if you pop an element from the stack you can't push it back, because you don't have some place to hold it, if you pop an element that's mean it goes directly to the output. ***For this case 3, please refer to [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) very good Answer.***

**Edit info:** I add the **case 2**, and treated the case where **number of elements is odd**. Add case 3, where there is no solution.

Comment: This assumes that the input is a string, and you have random access to all the input. But the OP says the input is a *sequence*. You are also using extra memory for `index_to_left` and `index_to_right`. But the question is clear that you can *only* use a stack. If all what you propose would be allowed, you wouldn't even need the stack. Then you would have indexes pointing at the first and last element and let them move to each other.

Comment: @trincot , yes indeed, the solution assume that we have Random access, and yes the solution as you said is just go from the end and the beginning toward the middle. what I understand is by using the data structure stack only (not another data structure ).  But as you said, if the element com from example in steaming so we can't do it. thank you very much for the clarification :)

Comment: The second solution does not treat the input as a sequence either. It puts values back in the input (as if it were a queue data structure), and then processes *that* input again. But that is really saying that you have a stack *and a queue* at your disposal. NB: you don't have to comment under my answer. Just putting my @-name here will notify me.

Comment: @trincot, yes indeed, you are right. So we are in the supposition like 1) the data comes in streaming, and 2) if you pop an element from the stack you can't push it back, because you don't have some place to hold it, if you pop an element that's mean it goes directly to the output.  I think **your answer is perfect for this case**.  Thank you sir. and also thank you for the advice about how to notify you.

Answer (score 0):

from itertools import permutations

seq = permutations(['a','b','c','d'])

for p in list(seq):
print(p)

Comment: I hope this helps you solving the problem.